# Pascal program does not show maximum value

Tags: counter, record, pascal, records, highest

Please help me my program just keeps on displaying the last name and number here is the program.
I really dont see what is wrong here but I do hope that you guys may see it please really need some help its killing my brain

```
Var
Counter:Integer;
MaxValue:Integer;
NumofVotes:Array[1..4]of Integer;
ChristianName:Array[1..4]of String;
Surname:Array[1..4]of String;
WinnerFName:String;
WinnerSName:String;
WinnerParty:String;
CandidateParty: Array[1..4] of String;

begin
  FOR Counter:= 1 to 4 Do
  If Counter= Counter Then
  begin
Writeln ('Please enter Christian name of Candidate ', Counter, ':');
Readln (ChristianName[Counter]);
Writeln ;
Writeln ('Please enter Surname of Candidate ', Counter, ':');
Readln (Surname[Counter]);
Writeln ;
Writeln ('Please enter number of votes received by Candidate ', Counter, ':');
Readln (NumOfVotes[Counter]);
Writeln ;
Writeln ('Please enter party of Candidate ', Counter, ':');
Readln (CandidateParty[Counter]);

  end;

  IF Counter = 1 THEN
begin
MaxValue:= NumofVotes[Counter];
WinnerFName:= ChristianName[Counter];
WinnerSName:= Surname[Counter];
WinnerParty:= CandidateParty[Counter];
end

ELSE
IF (NumofVotes[Counter]>MaxValue) THEN
begin
WinnerFName:= ChristianName[Counter];
WinnerSName:= Surname[Counter];
MaxValue:= NumofVotes[Counter];
WinnerParty:= CandidateParty[Counter]
end;
Writeln ;
Writeln ('The winner of the elections for this constituency is:');
Writeln ('FirstName: ', WinnerFName, ' Surname: ', WinnerSName);
Writeln ('From the ', WinnerParty);
Writeln (WinnerFName, ' has won with ', MaxValue, ' votes');
Writeln ;
Writeln  ;
Writeln ('Press <Enter> to end');
Readln  ;

end.
```

Comment: `If Counter= Counter Then` .. what kind of a test is that? A Counter is always a Counter.   `IF Counter = 1 THEN` .. you can't use 'for' loop index variable after the loop in pascal. Even if you could, how could it be '1', the last time it was '4'.

Comment: I did that because when I didn't do that the program came up weird it displayed all four questions at the same time instead of displaying them sequentially

Comment: Sorry I just took that out and it still works thanks much but what about it no testing for the maximum value??

Comment: If you properly format your code, you'll be able to see (by the level of indent) that the flow doesn't go quite like you think it does. **Learn to format your code** so you can read it and follow the execution path. (The **emphasis** is because this has been said here hundreds of times, and no one ever seems to notice it. It gets rather frustrating having to repeat yourself over and over again.) With that being said, **learn to format your code properly**. :-) For a clear example of why this is important, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23681072), which I didn't write.

Comment: Thanks much sir i'm just in high school trying to do some programming cuz I really like programming but i seemed to have got it to work here is what I got

Comment: @user - Counter is not 1. So take out the 'if counter = 1' block. What do you have? 'IF (NumofVotes[Counter]>MaxValue) THEN'. But you never assigned anything to 'MaxValue'. And there's no loop to compare anything after you read the values.

Comment: Sorry looks like i cant put it in inless its 8 hours after but ill show after

Comment: Also, not to nitpick but a Christian name is one given at baptism, traditionally. Not everyone is baptized, nor is everyone even of the religion where that might be a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to lack one pair of `begin ... end` keyword. As a result, the `for` instruction ends at the first `end` keyword, that is just after reading all candidates data. Then the `Counter` is `4` and the comparision in `IF Counter = 1` fails – execution proceeds to `ELSE`. There the uninitialized `MaxValue` is probably zero, so the fourth `NumofVotes` is greater than that, which eventually causes the fourth candidate to be printed.

To make the code do what you expected, add `begin` just after the `FOR ... DO` and close it with `end` just before `Writeln ; Writeln ('The winner ... is:');`